# Threading issue: Control is not coming back to the caller

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am facing an issue with respect to shared resources and I am using one `mutex` for synchronization. It is working fine with small number of `threads` [ example 10 threads], but I have an issue of `“control is not coming back”` (might be because of  deadlock)if I try with with more number of threads[example 60 threads].

**Note:** The code is a legacy code and is written in VC6, and I am maintaining the code.

**Explanation**
I have global data to share  between multiple device, for that I am using lock and unlock functions as below...

```
inline LONG SharedData::Lock()
{
    return WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, INFINITE );
}

inline BOOL SharedData::Unlock()
{
    return ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);
}
```

I am suspecting the destructor is causing some issue, below is the destructor...

```
SharedData::~ SharedData()
{
    Lock();
    try
    {
        m_lShareCnt--;
        if (m_lShareCnt < 1) 
        {
            //clearing the heap
        }

    }

    Catch(…) { }
    Unlock();

    if (!m_lShareCnt)
    {
        if(m_hMutex != NULL && m_hMutex != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        {
            CloseHandle(m_hMutex); 
            m_hMutex=NULL;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And the constructor as follows

```
SharedData:: SharedData ()
{
    try 
    {
        if (!m_hMutex) m_hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
        m_lShareCnt++;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell what might be wrong in the code?

Comment: It looks like the `m_lShareCnt` is outside the lock/unlock region. So by the time it is checked in the `if(...)` it may be changed and you have a race... When is the `SharedData` destructor run, i.e. what condition(s) cause it to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one problem is race condition on reference counter `m_lShareCnt` which is is not atomic. If non-atomic variable is modified concurrently by multiple threads then it's value might be unexpected.

The solution would be to make the reference counter atomic, or just protect the access to this variable with the mutex that you already use. Since you use ancient VC6, the easiest you can do is to use `InterlockedIncrement` and `InterlockedDecrement` methods for atomic read/write.